# Что за эффект это?(ссылка) И как его реализовать в jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Что за эффект это?([ссылка](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CaptionHoverEffects/index4.html)) И как его реализовать в jQuery? Что за функция такая? Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: зачем вам делать на js, то что сделано на css3 ? Это к тому-же невозможно всё равно без использования css.

Comment: Ну, на вебките вполне резво будет работать. Но это же — как спичку бензопилой забивать.

Answer (score 2):

Так [ВОТ](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/18/caption-hover-effects/) же ссылка на скачивание и документацию. Называется это **Caption Hover Effects**

Comment: а вы мой вопрос правильно прочитали??? Я спрашиваю как это на jQuery сделать. Если я задаю вопрос, то я знаю что там находится.

Comment: Если так хочется помучиться, то можно и жиквери помучить — она же позволяет менять стили и анимировать. Но только зачем жикверями делать анимацию стилей, когда это же самое можно (и правильнее) делать в самих стилях.

И что значит «что за эффект это»? Тебе что, термин, описывающий конкретно эту трансформацию нужен?

Answer (score 1):

Будет полезно [Sliding Boxes and Captions with jQuery](http://buildinternet.com/2009/03/sliding-boxes-and-captions-with-jquery/) + [Demo](http://s3.amazonaws.com/buildinternet/live-tutorials/sliding-boxes/index.htm)

Comment: это все я умею делать. Мне нужен тот эффект который на ссылке лежит

Answer (score 0):

Это CSS3/perspective/preserve-3d.

Comment: блин, я же на jQuery спрашиваю. Именно на jQuery возможно такое сделать и как?

Comment: Никакой jQuery тут не поможет, можно сделать только эмуляцию, примерно так http://jsfiddle.net/RubaXa/kVZDG/ , дальше, нужно развить код и сделать проверку на 3D и соответствующие стили.

Comment: А можно узнать, чем это вы так сделали, что при наведении, сама картинка так правильно смещается, а не сжимается? Это та часть с figcaption или?

Comment: Да ничем, она просто смещается на 80px и уезжает в overflow, в примере из статьи, ровно тоже самое. figcaption по умолчанию смещен на -160px и при наведении выезжает из overflow.